# Is the CPU cache line size modifiable? and how is data transmitted in cache blocks?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cache

I have two hardware related questions:

1- Is the CPU cache line size modifiable by the OS or is it hardwired in the CPU? the cache line sizes can be seen using `getconf -a` on Linux.

2- Assume my data cache line size is `64 bytes`, how is the data transferred from memory to CPU?
Is it parallel transmission? (meaning there are `64*8 = 512` little wires on the bus to move all the bits at once), or its serial transmission?

3- While we are at it, I have a 3rd question. How is the logic of `Cache placement policies` embedded in the CPU, is there software driving it (if so where is the software stored) or the logic is literally in the hardware somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In the past, some systems allowed boot-time configuration of cache sector size (to use Intel terminology, where cache line is a unit of coherence and cache sector is a unit of address tagging). For example, the PowerPC 7410 supported up to 2MiB of L2 cache of which a portion of that off-chip SRAM could be used instead for a directly mapped memory region. Increasing cache sector size allowed the fixed size on-processor-chip tag memory to support larger L2 caches, but the size of the off-chip SRAM was set at time of packaging/manufacture. By allocating, e.g., half of the capacity to directly-mapped memory, the sector size could be halved.

If an implementation has sufficient tag storage to cover the full capacity using a given cache sector size, the benefit of a larger sector size is very limited. The prefetch effect can be trivially provided by fetching adjacent sectors (with the benefit of ignoring such prefetches under high bandwidth utilization and other conditions). The way prediction and way memoization benefits could likewise be emulated at moderate cost.

If extra tag storage had other uses, configurability of cache sector sizes might be attractive. Such uses could include in-cache compression (where the data storage could fit more lines/sectors when the data is compressed), allocation of tag storage or data storage for other uses (e.g., if half of L3 data storage were allocated to a snoop filter, the cache sector size could be halved to increase meaningful capacity utilization or reduce conflict misses, if half of the tags were used for prefetch metadata, the cache sector size could be doubled to allow use of all the data storage), or optional use of a V-way cache mechanism (where the number of sets is doubled relative to the actual cache capacity: see Moinuddin K. Qureshi et al.'s "The V-Way Cache : Demand-Based Associativity via Global Replacement", [PDF](https://hps.ece.utexas.edu/pub/qureshi_isca05.pdf)) where turning off V-way would allow halving cache sector size.

(One might also design a non-uniform latency cache where doubling the cache sector size allowed a uniformly fast tag check, but since data access is slower such would benefit tag-data phased cache access as common in L2 and outer caches and the benefit would be modest. Partial tag way selection/miss detection would provide most of this benefit.)

With 64B cache lines and about 36-bit address tags, the storage overhead reduction for using 128B cache sectors is modest. (The benefit is increased if data storage uses a denser mechanism such as DRAM. If data storage is off-chip and tags are on-chip, larger sectors can become attractive since on-chip storage is more limited.)

With respect to transmission width, even before DDR memory, with its burst length of two urging a narrower-than-cache-line interface (DDR4 has a burst length of eight, though burst chop halves that), providing a "full-width" interface would have been excessively expensive. Even the high performance targeted Alpha 21064 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_21064)) only used a 128-bit wide data bus with 32B cache lines. (Note that before on-chip memory controllers, the off-chip memory controller could use a different width than processor data bus.)

With respect to replacement policy implementation, such is handled by specialized hardware. (Software controlled replacement has been proposed academically: [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=software+managed+cache+replacement).) Software-managed TLBs have been implemented, but even TLB management is most commonly done in hardware now.

Comment: Thank for this detailed info. So in modern day x64 chips, data transfer between usb and other peripherals like the memory is serial?

Comment: @Dan Universal *Serial* Bus and *Serial* ATA (two common interfaces) are 'purely' serial (not entirely pure because differential signaling is used which requires two 'wires' per lane). These are often attached to a support chip that connects to the processor chip by PCIe or a similar interface. Memory access is not fully parallel but is not serial either. PCIe favors narrow widths (synchronizing wide interfaces is more difficult) compared to PCI/AGP.

Comment: sorry I meant to ask `data transfer between CPU and other peripherals like the memory is serial?`. So when you say ` is not fully parallel but is not serial either.`, what is it exactly, what is it called?

Comment: @Dan Interfaces with one bit wide channels are considered serial, all others are considered parallel. The interface to the processor chip is often (more recently) PCIe (allowing direct connection to PCIe devices) or similar with distinct chips to translate non-PCIe I/O interfaces; direct support of USB and SATA on the processor chip is also common. A distinct interface like [HT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperTransport)) or [QPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect) has the advantage of also being an interprocessor interface as well as a chipset interface.